# Limiting the output of text to 50 characters in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to limit my text export in PHP to only 50 characters only

How could I modify the following statement to allow this?

```
$list[$key]['goods_attr'] = $rows['goods_attr'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do this in your SQL query if possible.

```
SELECT LEFT(subject , 50) FROM table
```

Or you could do it by using `substr` like this:

```
$list[$key]['goods_attr'] = substr($rows['goods_attr'], 0, 50);
```

Comment: I'm confused. Where does SQL come into play? I know the question isn't tagged with it nor does OP mention he's using it.

Comment: The variable `$rows` is (in most cases) an indication of the use of a database. But you are right too. And thats why it says "if possible".

Comment: Worth noting that for unicode strings it's better to use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt function of php [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp). It works as follow:

```
$string = "Hello world";
$string = substr($string,0,5);
```

it will print "Hello".

so in your case, it should be:

```
$list[$key]['goods_attr'] = substr($rows['goods_attr'],0,50);
```

That's it.